# Add a Hyperlink to an object that goes to a different file and specific sheet?

Tags: excel, object, hyperlink, vba

My end goal is to add a hyperlink to a Graph, using VBA, that (when clicked) opens a different saved workbook, then navigates to a specific sheet.

I know how to add a hyperlink to using VBA to open the file (see below) but I do not know how to specify which sheet I want it to open to.

```vb
Sub HyperlinkToFile()
'
' HyperlinkToFile Macro
'
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1), Address:= _
        "Book1.xlsm"
End Sub
```

I have figured out how to insert a hyperlink into a cell that goes to the file and the sheet I want by using the following:

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book2]Sheet1!A1", "CLICK HERE")
```

But I do not want it in a cell. Through using VBA, I am needing the hyperlink to be anchored on the chart then I need the hyperlink to open Book1 then navigate to Sheet1 then cell A1.

Is this possible? Because I have looked all over the internet and have not found a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a Macro to the Chart:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="E:\0\A\00 Move Form.xlsm"
    Sheets(1).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

When you click, you have a "Hyperlink"...